# Forces acting on an object about to hit the ground

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, free-body-diagram, free-fall

I have a simple question, If I have a spanner or (any object)  and I drop it. As it's just about to make contact with the ground what would the main forces acting on it be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Earth's gravity would be the main force acting upon it from the moment you let go, until the ground stops it's fall, or if high enough, until it reaches terminal velocity where air resistance equals the force of gravity and stops it's acceleration. If not at the north or south pole it  will also have a very slight centrifugal force (pseudo force) from the spin of the Earth, which will be strongest at the equator. There will also be highly negligible, but not quite zero, tidal forces acting upon it which will depend on it's position in relation to the Earth, moon, sun, etc. If anyone can think of any other forces please comment.

Comment: And there's friction from the air it's falling through. That's the second largest force.

Comment: What about if it's just hit the ground?

Comment: @hdhondt: yes, I was not explicit enough about air resistance, thanks

Comment: 2Benwright: When an object impacts an immobile surface it is an example of "normal force" for more info see  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Force#Normal_force